# Stopping untrusted code if taking too long

Tags: java, multithreading, security

I'm currently working on a program to run externally supplied code by the user (assume this case is justified). After a lot of research, I've found that most of the security involved with this can be handled by a SecurityManager; however, I'm struggling to find a way to kill the external code if it's taking too long and intending to be malicious. For example, if the external code looked like:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(50);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Oh well, keep running
    }
}
```

This would keep running forever, and `Thread.interrupt()` wouldn't do anything to stop the thread. Is there another method to stop a rogue thread that won't cause any issues? All I've come across is `Thread.stop()` however it doesn't seem to be an option with all the issues that seem to come with it. If not, are there other options available to run this code in a way that the program will still be able to interface with it directly?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. If the user can run malicious code (at all) then there is no safe interval to wait to try and kill it. Applets died for a reason. What do you really want to accomplish here?

Comment: Running untrusted code in the same JVM as your trusted code that is supposed to supervise it is a perilous idea. This is one of the reasons, but think about what would happen if it just allocated memory until the VM crashed with OOME.

Answer (score 0):

Just kill the java process executing the code.

Assuming an GNU/Linux or macOS system:

```
ps -ax | grep java # identify the correct process
kill $pid          # kill it
```

You could do this in Java by accessing the Runtime:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","cmd 1 goes here"});
```

Edit:

Considering that you would also have to compile the user-supplied code it would make sense to compile it and start it in its own jvm.

Furthermore executing the code in a completely virtual machine would be ideal, since then the code is sandboxed and can't access the host machine.

Comment: Wouldn't the process of the malicious code be the same as my original, essentially forcing the program to kill itself?

Comment: Yes, but you could also just start that process in another instance of the jvm

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there's no way in Java to just kill off a thread like you're describing.If the thread is executing, it just sets a flag and it's up to the thread to notice it or interrupt thread waiting or in sleep mode which will throw 
InterruptedException

The only way is to kill the process in which the thread is running.

```
 call System.exit(int)
```